# Neron model of multiplicative group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes, neron-model

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring and $K$ be its fraction field. Consider the multiplicative group scheme $\mathbb{G}_m$, as scheme $\mathbb{G}_m=Spec K[T,T^{-1}]$. How can we construct the Néron model of $\mathbb{G}_m$? Is it $Spec R[T,T^{-1}]$?

I have read it in Bosch's book chapter 10 example 5, but don't really understand the general steps. It is said the the Néron model is only of locally finite type and not of finite type.

Comment: Note that if $N$ is the Néron model of $\mathbb{G}_m$, then $N(R)$ has a natural bijection with $K^{\times} \cong \mathbb{G}_m(K)$. This rules out $(\mathbb{G}_m)_R$ as a Néron model. In general, $N$ must represent a functor that is $X \longmapsto O_X(X)[1/\pi]^{\times}$ on smooth affine $R$-schemes, where $\pi \in R$ is a uniformizer.

Comment: @hm2020: that isn’t the right correspondence, I think. One needs $A$ to be a smooth $R$-algebra, and the domain should be $\mathrm{Hom}_K(K[T,1/T],A \otimes K)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What are X and A ?

Comment: @Desunkid - If you look at the statement in Ex.5 you will find that the "identity component" of the Neron model $G$ is $G_e:=Spec(R[T,1/T])$. Are you claiming that $G_e=G$ in this particular case when $S:=Spec(R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments, taking $\operatorname{Spec}(R[T,T^{-1}])$ will not work. Instead you have to do a glueing process, which is described in the reference you mentioned. Let me recall the construction, which should also address your point about being locally of finite type, but not of finite type (Recall finite type=locally of finite type + quasi-compact).

Start with $\mathbb{Z}$-copies of $\mathbb{G}_{m,R}$, i.e. the scheme
$$ \coprod_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} X_i$$
where each $X_i\cong \mathbb{G}_{m,R}$ (this is $\pi^i\mathbb{G}_{m,R}$ in the notation of Bosch). Now you have to glue these together:
We identify all $X_i\times_R K\cong \mathbb{G}_{m,K}$ with each other via maps $\phi_{ij}:X_i\times_R K\xrightarrow{\cdot \pi^{j-i}} X_j\times_R K.$ This is an isomorphism, since $\pi$ is now invertible over $K$. Thus your Neron model is
$$ X=(\coprod_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} X_i)/\sim,$$
where $x_i\sim x_j$ if $\phi_{ij}(x_i)=x_j$, or equivalently $\phi_{ji}(x_j)=x_i$.

Now we see that $$ X\to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$$
is indeed locally of finite type: $X$ is covered by the $X_i\cong \mathbb{G}_{m,R}$ which are of finite type over $R$.

But it is not quasi-compact: For each $X_i$ we have a closed subscheme $Z_i$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}\subset \mathbb{G}_{m,R}$, where $k=R/\pi$ is the residue field, and these are by construction **not** glued together. As a consequence
$$ Z_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$$
whenever $i\neq j$. So the covering of $X$ by the (image of the) $X_i$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't admit a finite subcover: Omitting one $X_i$ means $Z_i$ will not be contained in your cover anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your grear answer. May we represent this model explitcitly? Can we construct a proper model for $\mathbb{G}_m$ ?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking for. The above is a description of the model of the multiplicative group. It is not affine, so I am uncertain how you would make it more concrete